# Frameworks/libraries that help turn 3D data into 2D shapes

Tags: library, framework, math, 3d, algorithms

Just like you can take a cube and flatten it into 6 sides, **I'd like to take a digital 3D model of a human and cut it into flat shapes** (think sewing patterns) with the help of a high-level framework/library.

To be more specific I need to

- be able to take simple measurements of the 3D model (bust/waist/hip sizes)
- be able to easily convert 3D to 2D (an arm would become 2 separate flat shapes)
- get the dimensions of the resulting 2D shapes
- work with a high-level library to do as much of the low-level math for me as possible

Taking a look at what's available I've only come across frameworks and libraries that work with rendering. As I do NOT need to render anything, could you recommend something that is minimal in meeting my above 4 point criteria?

OK languages are Javascript, PHP, Python, C, C++.

**Notes**:

- To be honest, I have no clue about the input but I expect it to be output from a future device like Project Tango. I want something open source.
- The input data is a 3D model of a human. What I'm not sure about is the file type but I assume this is irrelevant.

Comment: *based on the data* What data? What is your 3D input format? What are you willing to pay for the framework? Please [edit] your question.

Comment: *but I assume this is irrelevant* "I am looking for a program that converts my word processing files in to X, but I am not going to tell you what these files are". Well, then how should that program know? And you expect us to recommend X not knowing what data it will receive. Weird. You have a source that is going to supply those 3D models. Ask them.

Comment: Ok. I'm not looking for a program but a framework or library so perhaps I posted in the wrong place.